# prevent bootstrap conflict in a child element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap for most of the page, but I'd like to use custom css in a `div.col` to get a nicer looking table, but the bootstrap css is affecting some of the styles.

I'd like to *reset* all the styles for a specific div and it's children.

Are there any ways of dealing with this other than explicitly overloading every style bootstrap uses?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Ideally you should be able to just override the settings as opposed to completely resetting them.

Comment: don't use any class on the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset all the styles for a specific div, you can add the 'all: unset;' CSS property.

`<div style="all: unset;">...</div>`

This will undo ("unset") all the styles currently applied to that div (but not it's children), leaving you to add which ever ones you desire.

See it in action here (including how to apply to all child elements):

http://codepen.io/esr360/pen/kkogwm?editors=1100#0

This is a bootstrap accordion that has been "unstyled".

View browser support here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value

Unsurprisingly this doesn't work in IE.

Comment: this works for unsetting. I tried using a style with an id defined within to try to implement other styles, and glad to see it works. So it means that it doesn't reset those values tied to a style of an id defined after the reset.http://codepen.io/scorch/pen/QKrdYY?editors=1100 While this is good news, I wonder what are the rules for unset.

Comment: @Daniel it should just follow regular CSS inheritance. For example, in the example you linked, if you add `!important` to the unset, it again takes precedence, or if you change the selector to a more specific one, e.g. `#accordion.panel-group *` it again takes precedence. Likewise, if you make your new special selector less specific, such as by changing the id to a class, the styles are no longer applied.